# Are there any good tutorials / examples for developing a download manager in Adobe AIR using Flash CS4?`

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs4, download

I want to develop an AIR application that will let users of my website download multiple files in a single process. My database stores details of all the files uploaded by a user so I want them to be able to simply choose a location on local disk then download all files they have uploaded to this location.

Are there any good tutorials or source code examples for a simple yet effective AIR download manager developed using Flash CS4. I have come across a Flex based tutorial, so how would I go about using this to develop it in Flash?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you only using the Flash IDE? You could use Flex to create an Actionscript project and link it to your .fla via the DocumentClass, it may be more comfortable than actually coding in Flash. Of course you can do a similar setup with Flex, this way you could use your tutorial.

You may want to check the doc for the FileReference class:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

Answer (score 0):

AIR 2 with Flash and Flex Essential Training 
http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourseNoTabs.aspx?lpk2=68629